# Перевод строки во время

Tags: python

Как преобразовать время которое **Ввел**
00:00 в 12:00 a.m.
00:01 в 12:01 a.m.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `.replace('00:', '12:')` видимо так.  А, ещё а.м., тут надо подумать

Answer (score 0):

Немного другой формат надписи AM, PM, но зато из коробки:

```
import time

h24_time = input()
t = time.strptime(h24_time, "%H:%M")
h12_time = time.strftime("%I:%M %p", t)
print(h12_time)
```

Comment: не ошибку пишет прикреплю в вопрос фото

Comment: Поменяйте через replace AM на a.m. и PM аналогично. А вообще если это учебная задачка, то это надо было писать изначально. Тогда смысл в том чтобы вы научились переводить из одного формата в другой и написали свой алгоритм.